# Sharing files linux to linux, or linux to windows

Tags: networking, samba, sharing

How do you share files in elementary OS? What is the install procedure for Samba? I cannot see elementary OS on my network at all, Linux or Win

Really need to be able to stream content from Win to elementary OS, could you please advise, i know it's not ideal but it is what it is

Cannot see elementary OS from my UB Mate laptop, even if I turn on the sharing in elementary OS

Comment: The Sharing in elementary OS is a DLNA service, not SAMBA, I alway hope that they can add the support for setting up a SAMBA service in Panthoen-Files.